# Customize Barplot in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, bar-chart

I would like to draw exactly (or something similar to) this following figure A:

[image: Figure A]

I used this following code. But definitely would need some help to customize my figure.

Any help is welcome.

Thanks in advance

```
groupe2<-rep(c(rep("P",4),rep("I",4)),3)
groupe<-rep(c("PPP","PPI","PII","PIP","III","IIP","IPP","IPI"),3)
OR_A<-c(1.00,0.86,0.90,0.88,0.70,0.77,0.77,0.68)
ICinf_A<-c(NA,0.70,0.76,0.72,0.61,0.61,0.60,0.50)
ICsup_A<-c(NA,1.06,1.06,1.07,0.81,0.96,1.00,0.92)
OR_B<-c(1.00,0.97,0.81,1.01,0.58,0.61,0.73,0.69)
ICinf_B<-c(NA,0.78,0.62,0.77,0.52,0.50,0.61,0.57)
ICsup_B<-c(NA,1.20,1.05,1.28,0.65,0.71,0.81,0.82)
OR_C<-c(1.00,1.03,0.65,0.86,0.37,0.47,0.68,0.58)
ICinf_C<-c(NA,0.84,0.50,0.67,0.33,0.40,0.59,0.49)
ICsup_C<-c(NA,1.27,0.86,1.10,0.41,0.56,0.78,0.69)
outcome<-c(rep("PC M",8), rep("RIC M",8), rep("RIC C",8))

OR<-c(OR_A,OR_B,OR_C)
ICinf<-c(ICinf_A,ICinf_B,ICinf_C)
ICsup<-c(ICsup_A,ICsup_B,ICsup_C)

dataOR<-data.frame(OR,groupe,outcome,groupe2,ICinf,ICsup)

#pour mettre l'ordre qu'on veut pour la légende (par défaut : ordre alphabétique)
dataOR[, "groupe"] <- factor(dataOR[, "groupe"] , 
                             levels = c("PPP","PPI","PII","PIP","III","IIP","IPP","IPI"))

##########
##########


ggplot(dataOR, aes(fill=outcome, y=OR, x=groupe)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Blues")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=ICinf, ymax=ICsup), width=.2,position=position_dodge(.9))+
  #theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill="lightgreen"))+
  geom_hline(yintercept=1)
```

[image: Figure A]

Regarding the labels for figure A:

For example:

> PPP, etc...

would be at the place of

> Basic Activity Level, etc...

UPDATE

UPDATE

[image: FIGURE C]

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want to use the facetting functionality of `ggplot`. Some slight modifications to your code gives you the facets, removes the x-axis, and adds the points:

```
ggplot(dataOR, aes(fill=outcome, y=OR, x=factor(1))) + #Reset x-axis
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Blues")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=ICinf, ymax=ICsup), width=.2,position=position_dodge(.9))+
  geom_point(position=position_dodge(.9)) + #Add points
  geom_hline(yintercept=1) + 
  facet_wrap(~groupe, nrow = 1) +  #Add facets
  scale_x_discrete(name = NULL, labels = NULL, breaks = NULL) #Remove labels
```

[image]

---

Per the comment below, to change the colors of the specific groups you can do:

```
colors = c(brewer.pal(3, "Blues"), rep(brewer.pal(3,"Reds"), 3), rep(brewer.pal(3, "Blues"), 4))

ggplot(dataOR, aes(fill=interaction(outcome, groupe), y=OR, x=factor(1))) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors, guide = FALSE) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=ICinf, ymax=ICsup), width=.2,position=position_dodge(.9))+
  geom_point(position=position_dodge(.9)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=1) + 
  facet_wrap(~groupe, nrow = 1) + 
  scale_x_discrete(name = NULL, labels = NULL, breaks = NULL)
```

[image]

Comment: Woow thank you  a bunch mike Mike ! A very last question? How could I color the 3 first columns (PPI, PIP, PII) in red and then the 4 other (III, IPP, IPI, IPP) in green for example? Of coure the first column PPP would stay grey. Thanks, Thanks

Comment: Hi Mike ! Thank you for your update. However what I meant is to color the top only and keep the labeling. However it seems like, in order to do so, I better used scratch for labelling (in stead of the 3 bleu colors) and use the colors to dichotomize Group A and Group B.  I updated (UPDATE FIGURE) my message incase you could help for this. Thank you

Comment: @Peter, that again will be harder. Probably not the best idea to keep updating your question...

Comment: That's true ! Any idea how I could perform this?

Comment: @Peter, I think you'd probably have to convert it to a `gtable` and mess with adding those three boxes as `grobs`

Answer (score 1):

I think I caught everything that you wanted from the first plot. I did a few tweaks, some with `theme` parameters and some a little hacky:

- Added a thin line around the bars, about the same color as the panel background, so the bars aren't all squeezed up next to each other
- Changed the fill to skip over the lightest colors in the palette, just because the light blue is hard to see on the light gray background (feel free to drop this)
- Added a `geom_point` but set it to not show up in the legend
- Expanded the y scale to get rid of the gap at the bottom of the bars
- Facetted on a single row and with free x scaling
- Dropped the legend title
- Put the legend on top with a border and rectangular keys
- Added black axis lines on both x and y axes
- Dropped axis ticks and x-axis tick labels
- Dropped x grid
- Put axis titles in bold.

I think that's everything that differed between the two!

```r
ggplot(dataOR, aes(fill=outcome, y=OR, x=groupe)) +
    geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity", color = "gray95", size = 0.25) + 
    # scale_fill_brewer(palette="Blues")+
    scale_fill_manual(values = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(5, "Blues")[3:5]) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=ICinf, ymax=ICsup), width=.4, position=position_dodge(.9))+
    geom_hline(yintercept=1) +
    geom_point(position = position_dodge(0.9), size = 0.5, show.legend = F) +
    scale_y_continuous(expand = expand_scale(mult = c(0, 0.05))) +
    facet_wrap(~groupe, nrow = 1, scales = "free_x") +
    labs(fill = NULL) +
    theme(legend.position = "top", 
                legend.key.height = unit(0.2, "cm"), 
                legend.background = element_rect(color = "black", size = 0.4), 
                axis.line = element_line(color = "black"),
                axis.text.x = element_blank(),
                axis.ticks = element_blank(),
                panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
                axis.title = element_text(face = "bold"))
#> Warning: Removed 3 rows containing missing values (geom_errorbar).
```

[image]

Created on 2018-05-04 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).